# passing function from a parent container to a child container using swipeout in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to pass a function from a parent container to a child container in react native. On the screen the user is presented with a list of items where the user can swipe the list to reveal more options

Child

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';
    import { Container, Content, Button, Icon, List, ListItem,Body,Left,Thumbnail } from 'native-base';
    import Swipeout from 'react-native-swipeout';

    const swipeBtns = [
      {
        component: (
          <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                flexDirection: 'column',
              }}
          >
            <Image source={require('../../../assets/imgs/trash.png')} />
          </View>
        ),
        backgroundColor: '#f15151',
        onPress: () => {
          onDeleteGroup()

        }

    },
    {
      component: (
        <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              flexDirection: 'column',
            }}
        >
          <Image source={require('../../../assets/imgs/edit.png')} />
        </View>
      ),
      backgroundColor: '#1b6faa',
      onPress: () => {
        console.log("Edit Item");
      }
    }
    ];

    const CreatedGroupsScreen = ({navigation, myGroups, onDeleteGroup}) => (

       <Container>
           <Content contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent:'center'}}>
           <Button 
           onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('CreateGroup')}
           style={{width:'90%', alignSelf:'center', margin:10}} block bordered iconRight>
               <Icon name="add"/>
               <Text style={{fontSize:15}}>
                Create New Group
               </Text>
           </Button>
                <List
                dataArray={myGroups}
                renderRow = {(item)=>{
                return (
                  <Swipeout right={swipeBtns} autoClose="true" backgroundColor= 'transparent'>

                <ListItem 
                onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('GroupPosts')}
                avatar>
                  <Left>
                  <Thumbnail source={require(`../../../assets/imgs/group.png`)} />
                  </Left>

                  <Body>
                    <Text style={{fontWeight:'700', fontSize:16, color:'#1b6faa'}}>{item.groupName}</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:15, color:'#5f5f5f'}} >{item.about}</Text>
                  </Body>

                </ListItem>
                </Swipeout>
                )}
                }>
              </List>
           </Content>
       </Container>

    );
export default CreatedGroupsScreen;
```

Parent

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert} from 'react-native';
import CreatedGroupsScreen from './CreatedGroupsScreen';

class CreatedGroupsContainer extends Component{

  state = {
    myCreatedGroups: [
      { groupName: 'group1', about: 'bla bla bla' },
      { groupName: 'group2',   about: 'bla bla abla' },
      { groupName: 'group3', about: 'bla bla bla' },
    ],

  }

handleDeleteGroup = () => {
  Alert.alert(
    'Delete Group',
    'Are you sure to delete group?',
    [
      {text: 'No', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
      {text: 'Yes, Delete', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'}
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
  )
}
  render() {
    return (
     <CreatedGroupsScreen
     navigation = {this.props.navigation}
     myGroups = {this.state.myCreatedGroups}
     onDeleteGroup = {this.handleDeleteGroup}
     />
    );
  }
}
export default CreatedGroupsContainer;
```

When i swipe on the list and tap on the delete icon, an error messages pops up the screen saying "Cant find variable onDeleteGroup". Any help on how to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

`onDeleteGroup` could not be found cause it's not in the correct scope in the child component. So, move the configuration (`const swipeBtns`) for the `<Swipeout />` component to inside the `< CreatedGroupsScreen />` component itself, for example:

```
const CreatedGroupsScreen = ({navigation, myGroups, onDeleteGroup}) => {
   const swipeBtns = [
     CONFIG_GOES_HERE
   ];

   return (
    <Container>
       <Content contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent:'center'}}>
       <Button 
       onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('CreateGroup')}
       style={{width:'90%', alignSelf:'center', margin:10}} block bordered iconRight>
           <Icon name="add"/>
           <Text style={{fontSize:15}}>
            Create New Group
           </Text>
       </Button>
            <List
            dataArray={myGroups}
            renderRow = {(item)=>{
            return (
              <Swipeout right={swipeBtns} autoClose="true" backgroundColor= 'transparent'>

            <ListItem 
            onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('GroupPosts')}
            avatar>
              <Left>
              <Thumbnail source={require(`../../../assets/imgs/group.png`)} />
              </Left>

              <Body>
                <Text style={{fontWeight:'700', fontSize:16, color:'#1b6faa'}}>{item.groupName}</Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize:15, color:'#5f5f5f'}} >{item.about}</Text>
              </Body>

            </ListItem>
            </Swipeout>
            )}
            }>
          </List>
       </Content>
   </Container>
 );

};
```

Comment: @developer What error was thrown? The same like in your question? Could you provide that specific error?

Comment: a constant cannot be in a constant, it underlines the second one red